# Is there anyway to create Laravel Websocket Server without 3rd party solution?

Tags: javascript, laravel, websocket, pusher, pusher-js

I am preparing to build a WebSockets system to have a bidirectional communication from my server to my clients through WebSockets.

I know that Laravel now very well supports 3rd parties like [Pusher Channels](https://pusher.com/channels) and `Ably`.
There are also some other ways that are also very convenient and simple to use such as [Laravel Websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets), `soketi`, `laravel-echo-server`.

But my problem is client-side **cannot include 3rd party Client Library**. My client-side is a Cross-platform Game based on Javascript and HTML5. I can **only** connect client-side to server-side through [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).
As far as I know, when using 3rd party for server-side, I should use their JS Client Library like `pusher/pusher-js`, `laravel/echo` ... Therefore, I can't find any documents if I want to use them with [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

My goal is to find the best and most suitable solution for both client and server side.

What I have tried?

### IDEA 1: Convert pusher.js to my own js

I spent 2 weeks on this. I see this as possible and some functions might work. However, it will take a long time if I want to convert the whole thing.

### IDEA 2: Using Pusher and connect the client via Pusher Channels Protocol

I have tested them as follows

`var socket = new WebSocket('ws://ws-[cluster_name].pusher.com:[port]/app/[key]');`

It worked. I can see them connected on the Pusher Debug Console. However, I can't find any documentation regarding the basics like Subcribe channel, Listening events, Send message to other client, Ping, Pong, ...

### IDEA 3: Using [Laravel Websockets](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets)

Like idea 2, I couldn't find any documentation or examples.

### IDEA 4: Using NodeJS instead of Laravel. Choose [ws](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) packages

I tried it and it worked as expected. [WS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws) is really simple but it is exactly what I want. However I don't have many years of NodeJS experience. Therefore, I feel there are many risks if I choose it to build a new project.

Could you tell me a best way to deal with this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Please check: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/broadcasting You missed this part: The laravel-websockets and soketi packages provide Pusher compatible WebSocket servers for Laravel. These packages allow you to leverage the full power of Laravel broadcasting without a commercial WebSocket provider. -> The documentation for their use is literally the same.

Comment: Hi @daniel-l, I have read and tested them before.
```laravel-websockets``` is actually interoperable with traditional Websocket. However, they do document how to use ```pusher-js``` on the client-side.  Same with [link](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/139)

Comment: You use it exactly the same way you'd use it with Pusher. All you need is [a couple configuration variables](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/pusher#pusher-configuration) to point it at the `laravel-websockets` or `socketi` instance instead of Pusher.com. Everything else works the same. The `pusher-js` JS client is what you want, even if you're using a Pusher alternative on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

The Pusher and Laravel Echo JavaScript clients work with *any* Pusher-compatible websockets host. (Pusher uses websockets, too.)

All it takes is a little configuration; see, for example, Laravel Websockets' guide on [configuring Laravel](https://docs.soketi.app/getting-started/backend-configuration/laravel-broadcasting) and then [configuring Echo](https://docs.soketi.app/getting-started/client-configuration/laravel-echo). Both steps point your Pusher requests at your chosen Pusher *replacement* instead.

No need to write your own library or manually consume websocket data.